# If I have an array in excel like (1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0) a

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

If I have an array in excel like

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H

1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

and I want to check the condition that IF even one 1 exists I want to get output as BUY, and if all are 0, then not buy. Can you please tell  me how to get this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the entire array in a **single** cell ?

Comment: No they are in different columns, in the same row

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`=IF(COUNTIF(A1:H1,1)>0,"BUY","Remaind")`

Comment: Using `COUNTIF` is unnecessary, as his array consists only of 0's and 1's. Using `SUMPRODUCT` or `SUM` is simpler and more efficient. Additionally, besides this one difference, your answer is identical to mine, so why did you find it necessary to post this answer?

Comment: What you said is false. `SUMPRODUCT` in performance and formula working is more complicated. In this simple situation I advise you using the more clear and same solution.

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` works identically to `SUM` if the input is only one cell range. I agree with your statement if there are multiple cell ranges, but in this case there is only one cell range.

Comment: Right. each of them (`SUMPRODUCT` and `COUNTIF` and ...) are corresponding in this case. Seems for who asked this question, understand the `COUNT ` formula may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
= IF(SUMPRODUCT(<array>)>0,"buy","don't buy")
```

where `<array>` is a cell range, e.g. `A1:H1`.